# How many joules of energy does America use everyday?

Tags: energy

When considering all forms of energy the US uses to power itself, for example fossil fuels, solar, and nuclear energy, how much does America use a day? I'm looking for an answer in joules and a reference to the data source in which the answer is derived.

*I'm not a student or a physicist. I'm just a layman who understands the basics concept of energy and would like to know if there is anyone here who can answer this question. I would be happy to clarify the question if it seems unclear, just leave a comment.*

Comment: This is information which can (probably) be found on the internet using a search engine. It is not something which requires physics to explain or quantify.

Comment: I needed this in the past.  It took me about one minute to find it using a search engine.

Comment: You are right! I just searched google and this showed up, but as of now there is no answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: Try digging around on the website of the [Energy Information Administration](http://www.eia.gov/).

Comment: I've taken a look at the rules. There is actually something I'm trying to get a number on and it requires physics computation of energy/work, but I''m having a real hard time asking the right question or set of questions without being, I guess, 'off topic'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's an easy find on Google. About 25000 TWh in 2013 of primary energy. See [Energy in the US](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_in_the_United_States)
and I'm sure there's more data you can find online.

$1~\textrm{Joule}  = 1~\textrm{ Wsec, i.e,}~ 1~\textrm{ watt-second}.$ You can do the conversion:

$25000~\textrm{TWh} = 25000  \times 10^{12} \times 3.6 \times 10^3 = 10^{20}~\textrm J$  approx.

It was relatively constant for a few years according to the wiki article. If you need an exact number for an specific year just go find it.

Comment: I'm really not so good at math. I am curious, if that work done was averaged throughout the day evenly, how heavy is the weight being pushed for that day?

Comment: 1 joule is work done by 1 Newton of force lifting something 1 meter. Since g= 10 in those units, that's lifting 0.1 kg. So it'll lift $10^{19}$ kg 1 meter. A kg is about 2.2 lbs, so 100kg about 1 Ton (approximating). So lifting about $10^{16}$ Tons 1 meter. That number of Tons is about 10,000 trillion Tons, lifted 1 meter.